# Por que é que não consigo instanciar uma class do linq

Tags: c#, classes

Estou a tentar instanciar a seguinte class da biblioteca linq

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace System.Linq.Expressions
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents accessing a field or property.
    public class MemberExpression : Expression
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the containing object of the field or property.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An System.Linq.Expressions.Expression that represents the containing object of
        //     the field or property.
        public Expression Expression { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the field or property to be accessed.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The System.Reflection.MemberInfo that represents the field or property to be
        //     accessed.
        public MemberInfo Member { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns the node type of this System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Expression.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType that represents this expression.
        public sealed override ExpressionType NodeType { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new expression that is like this one, but using the supplied children.
        //     If all of the children are the same, it will return this expression.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   expression:
        //     The System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Expression property of the result.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     This expression if no children are changed or an expression with the updated
        //     children.
        public MemberExpression Update(Expression expression);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Dispatches to the specific visit method for this node type. For example, System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression
        //     calls the System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression).
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   visitor:
        //     The visitor to visit this node with.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The result of visiting this node.
        protected internal override Expression Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor);
    }
}
```

A forma como estou a tentar instanciar é a seguinte

```
public class Exemple
{
  public void ExampleMethod()
  {
     var memberExpression = new MemberExpression(); 
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Se é uma class que não é abstrata qual a razão de não poder instanciar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem já descreve o problema:

> 'MemberExpression' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
> arguments

Ou seja, não tem um contrutor com 0 argumentos

Se olhar o código fonte aqui: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/MemberExpression.cs

Vai encontrar isso:

```
public class MemberExpression : Expression {
        private readonly Expression _expression;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the field or property to be accessed.
        /// </summary>
        public MemberInfo Member {
            get { return GetMember(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the containing object of the field or property.
        /// </summary>
        public Expression Expression {
            get { return _expression; }
        }

        // param order: factories args in order, then other args
        internal MemberExpression(Expression expression) {

            _expression = expression;
        }
}
```

Ou seja, a classe tem um construtor que requer um objeto do tipo `Expression`, e que ainda é `internal`, ou seja, como não é `public` não tem acesso a ele, a ideia é evitar que seja construido fora do assembly.

Se precisar criar uma instância, na documentação da classe `Expression` tem exemplos: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0